# BST. Binary Search Tree. Порядковый номер. Не понятна суть того, что по методичке просят сделать. (У автора нет возможности спросить)

Tags: c++, структуры-данных, бинарное-дерево

Мне нужно реализовать на С++ "Определение порядкового номера для элемента с заданным ключом. Трудоёмкость операции – O (log n)." для BSTree (Дерева бинарного поиска). 
Вопрос: **Что значит *"порядковый номер элемента"* для дерева BST?** 
 Может есть какое-то конкретное определения что это?  Порядковый номер при обходе?(+обходить по разному можно) при вставке? или это номер того на какой высоте узел в дереве находится?

Comment: Порядок обхода однозначно задается предикатом сравнения ключей элементов (от меньшего к большему). Собственно для этого дерево и строится.

Comment: @user7860670 это то понятно. Я не понимаю что может значить "Порядковый номер элемента дерева".

Comment: Все элементы образуют последовательность в которой каждый элемент имеет порядковый номер. Попробуйте проитерироваться по контейнеру `std::map` для примера

Comment: @user7860670 чел ты на вопрос так и не ответил. Понятно что есть последовательность. Вопрос в том, что считается за последовательность я  даже перечислил возможные догадки....

Comment: Я уже ответил, что это за последовательность, в своем первом комментарии...

Comment: Я лишь предположил что порядок обхода может являться определяющим фактором порядка элемента, но это не значит, что это так. Как обходить я и так знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен порядковый номер в сортированном массиве ключей, он совпадает с порядком вывода узла при **центрированном обходе** (left - node- right), однако сам обход вам выполнять не нужно, т.к. указано время O(log n)

Answer (score -1):

Порядковый номер элемента для BST это его индекс) Ну или глубина(высота).